# Have either Empathy or Ekiga SIP clients use IPv6 instead of messing with NAT?

Tags: empathy, ipv6, ekiga, sip

How can I get either Empathy or Ekiga to work over IPv6 so I can avoid all the complexity of dealing with NAT?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!